# Load tab (Fragment) only once when it is shown for the first time and retain it for later use

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, material-design, android-tabs

I am able to show `Fragments` as tabs using `ViewPager`.

What I want to achieve is,

1. The contents of a fragment should be loaded only when it is selected as the current tab.
2. Once a tab is shown and is loaded, then whenever I come back to the same tab then it is retained, i.e. not loaded again.

I know to retain all tabs I can use the following,

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4); // 4 is total number of tabs
```

But when I do this, **it loads all 4 tabs at the very beginning** i.e. calls `onCreateView` of all 4 tabs in the beginning. How can I make it load only when it is shown for the first time and then retain for later use.

P.S. This functionality exists in Twitter and Facebook Android apps.

Comment: Why Down Vote ? Please write down the reason.

Comment: If you hover over the downvote button, it gives the possible reasons: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".

Comment: Is there a solution for this?! I too can NOT get the Tabs to reload after the init load. So it starts with the "default" tab and works fine, then click the second tab and everything is fine as well, when i return to the first tab , its not calling onCreate function...

Answer (score 3):

To retain the fragments make your view pager adapter extend FragmentPagerAdapter instead of FragmentStatePagerAdapter. The fragments will be retained in memory, so there is no need to set the page limit. To fire the things you have to load upon user visibility, just extend setUserVisibleHint as mentioned above.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser && myData == null) {
        loadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Will surely try that. And sorry for late reply.

Comment: Method setUserVisibleHint is deprecated in androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

The android fragments do provide below method

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    }
```

This method gets called in when the fragments become visible on screen only.
So whatever the code you are executing in `onCreateView()` can be managed in this method.

Comment: The contents of fragments are loaded in `onCreateView()` method. Do you want to say I should put the code of onCreateView in this method ?

Comment: The data loading can be handled in onCreateView()

Comment: Then how to retain it ?